# Odd Visual Studio Checking Variable Value

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Really weird... So I'm trying to save the page index of my gridview in a Session Variable and then reset the index when the user navigates back to the gridView. Here's my code below;

```
Protected Sub Page_PreRender(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        If Not Session("CurrentPage") Is Nothing AndAlso 
Session("CurrentPage") <= GridView1.PageCount Then
            GridView1.PageIndex = Session("CurrentPage")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Well the weird thing is that when I breakpoint on the second IF above and hover over pageCount it says it's 0. If I then go into my watch window and look at it (0 once again), then go back to my code and hover again it's 2 (which it should be)! I can then Continue past the break point and the page displays on page 2 as it should. However, and this is where it gets really weird, if I remove the breakpoint and run it I end up on page 1! So it's as if the `PageCount` hasn't updated unless I've put a breakpoint on it and specifically looked at it. Anyone explain this behaviour and how to get around it?!

**UPDATE**

Here's a pic of the values of the variables in question. You can see the PageIndex wasn't updated because it never entered the `IF` statement because moments earlier the PageCount was 0!! I can't be the only one stumped by this :/

Image of variable values: [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok bit hacky but it works. Simply used;

```
If Not Session("CurrentPage") Is Nothing Then
    GridView1.PageIndex = DirectCast(Session("CurrentPage"), Integer)
End If
```

Couldn't get the GridView.PageCount to equal 2 except by going into the WatchWindow and refresh the value field (would be hard to explain to your everyday online user how to do that so that wasn't really an option :P ). So I tried just leaving it out. Works fine now. Could possibly run into a page does not exist error but I imagine it would be quite unlikely as the number of pages doesn't change much at all and `Session("CurrecntPage")` variable is updated quite regularly.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you may need to cast your Session value to Integer

```
    If Not Session("CurrentPage") Is Nothing AndAlso 
               DirectCast(Session("CurrentPage"),
                                           Integer) <= GridView1.PageCount Then
         GridView1.PageIndex = DirectCast(Session("CurrentPage"),Integer)
    End If
```

Comment: And as a follow-on to that, it would be a Good Idea if the OP used `Option Strict On`.

Comment: Hmm nope, the problem lies with my PageCount, it's still 0. Changing my currentPage type doesn't affect it.